# Comparing dates in different dataframe columns and updating a new column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I'm having a little trouble updating a column based on values in other columns in a pandas dataframe. What I would like to do is update the column `NEWVAL` based on the 3 date columns below:

```
   date1    |    date2     |     date3     | Val1 |   NEWVAL
---------------------------------------------------------------
2010-01-02  |  2010-01-07  |   2010-01-14  |  2   |     2
2010-01-10  |  2010-01-23  |   2010-05-06  |  5   |     
2010-01-02  |  2010-01-07  |   2010-01-14  |  7   |
```

If the month in `date1` or `date2` is equal to the same year and month in `date3`, then I want to update the column `NEWVAL` with the value in `Val1`. So in the example above, since the year `2010` and month is `01`, the value in column `Val1` gets put into `NEWVAL`

I also have a slight modification to this problem where I not only wish to update `NEWVAL` based on the 3 date columns but also on the `Group1` and `Group2` columns as shown below:

```
   date1    |    date2     |    date3     | Group1 |  Group2 |  Val1  |  NEWVAL
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2010-01-02  |  2010-01-07  |  2010-01-14  |   AA   |   AAAA  |   2    |    2
2010-01-10  |  2010-01-23  |  2010-05-06  |   bb   |   AAAA  |   5    |     
2010-04-28  |  2010-04-23  |  2010-04-19  |   bb   |   bbbb  |   7    |    7
```

I apologize if this is an easy question - if I were not working with dates, I could do it easily, but I'm having trouble using the `datetime64[ns]` data type (and I don't wish to convert it if possible), so if anyone could help out I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT: The first part I was able to do, but is there a way to do the same thing by group, as in the second example I have?

Comment: 2nd row expect to get what NEWVAL? NaN?

Comment: Yes, it should just be a NULL/NaN value :)

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
data = {'date1': {0: '2010-01-02', 1: '2010-01-10', 2: '2010-04-28'}, 
        'date2': {0: '2010-01-07', 1: '2010-01-23', 2: '2010-04-23'}, 
        'date3': {0: '2010-01-14', 1: '2010-05-06', 2: '2010-04-19'}, 
        'Val1': {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 7}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`df`

```
    date1       date2       date3       Val1
0   2010-01-02  2010-01-07  2010-01-14  2
1   2010-01-10  2010-01-23  2010-05-06  5
2   2010-04-28  2010-04-23  2010-04-19  7
```

dtypes of date* is object not datetime for questioner.

---

**Code**

1. extract year and month

```
s = df['date1'].str[:-3]
```

`s`

```
0    2010-01
1    2010-01
2    2010-04
Name: date1, dtype: object
```

2. chk all date of row is same year and month

```
cols = ['date1', 'date2', 'date3']
cond1 = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str[:-3]).eq(s, axis=0).all(axis=1)
```

`cond1`

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```

3. make NEWVAL column

```
out = df.assign(NEWVAL=df['Val1'].where(cond1))
```

`out`

```
    date1       date2       date3       Val1    NEWVAL
0   2010-01-02  2010-01-07  2010-01-14  2       2.0
1   2010-01-10  2010-01-23  2010-05-06  5       NaN
2   2010-04-28  2010-04-23  2010-04-19  7       7.0
```

Comment: Thanks! I was just wondering, how would it change if the date columns were `datetime64[ns]` values?

Comment: If you're ding only this work, it won't make much of difference.